# PHP search query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a database in which I store data exported by different sensors. When searching in the db I know what is in one column in a row but I need to print a different column in that row that starts with a know characters. I'm trying to do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 301; $i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM full_dump WHERE file_name='J7091-01.TXT' AND ".$row['field_'.$i.'']." LIKE 'OS' ")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['field_'.$i.''];
    }
}
```

I'm getting this result:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\t1.php on line 11
>    
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'OS'' at line 1

I have tried searching using:

```
... and LIKE '%OS%'
```

with no luck.
Whant am I doing wrong?

My mysql version is 5.6.16

Comment: You have an extra single quote after `$i.'` and where you have defined `$row`

Comment: Also, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for a while. Consider switching to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use the variable `$row` in the query, instead you should do it like this-

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT .....AND field_".$i." LIKE 'OS' ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil Mittal. I don't get that error now but I get no output just an empty page now. I need to print the field that starts with the searched word

Comment: Solved instead of 'OS' I used '%OS%' and worked.
Thank to everyone

Comment: I have a quick question. In the row I search I have more the one column that starts with the search word. At output I get 3-4 words (results), how do I print only the last one?

Comment: If need only the last one, you can change your query- `desc limit 0,1`; only the last one will be returned by the query

Comment: Tried that but still no luck.

Comment: Tried that. A row in my table looks like this id, file_name, field[1-300], date. ... 2, file.txt, ..., os00000,...os000010,.....os0000001,...,date. I need to print only the last os0000001

Comment: Im not able to get you this way. It would be better if you can post another question explaining your query..

Comment: I managed to get what I want. What I did was this while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $a=$row['field_'.$I.''];} echo $a; and it prints the last search value.